# How to Bind a TextBox in DataGrid to a List in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, wpfdatagrid

Am working on a new Wpf project and struggling with Binding a TextBox in DataGrid to a List of objects in Wpf.
Can anyone help me to fix?

This is my code (simplified version) to generate the Datagrid rows by binding my **Orders** object.
User can changed the Order Items and it should bind into the underline object.
Once user clicked the **Read orders** button i am displaying the changes in the textblock. Issue: the changes in TextBox are not updating into the Orders object.

```
ObservableCollection<StxOrdr> Orders = new ObservableCollection<StxOrdr>();

private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Orders.Add(new StxOrdr() { ID = 1, Desc = "Order-#1", Item1 = "11", Item2 = "12", Item3 = "13" });
    Orders.Add(new StxOrdr() { ID = 2, Desc = "Order-#2", Item1 = "21", Item2 = "22", Item3 = "23" });
    Orders.Add(new StxOrdr() { ID = 3, Desc = "Order-#3", Item1 = "31", Item2 = "32", Item3 = "33" });                        
    Dg2.ItemsSource = Orders;
}

private void ReadUpdatedOrders(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TxtBlk.Text = "";
    foreach (StxOrdr odr in Orders)
    {
        TxtBlk.Text += string.Format("{0}:   {1} - {2} - {3}\n", odr.Desc, odr.Item1, odr.Item2, odr.Item3);
    }
}
```

Window Xml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Dg2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,295,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="230" Width="451"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Orders}" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Desc" Binding="{Binding Desc}"   Width="80"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item 1" Binding="{Binding Item1}"  Width="60"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item 2" Binding="{Binding Item2}"  Width="60"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item 3" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Item3, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="60" />                            
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
    
<TextBlock x:Name="TxtBlk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="489,295,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="  Updated order details:" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="176" Width="408" Background="#FFFFFCBC"/>
<Button x:Name="Btn2_Copy" Content="Read Orders" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="489,476,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Click="ReadUpdatedOrders"/>
```

**Screenshot of the UI window**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most things looks correct. Make sure that Orders.cs implements INotifyPropertyChanged and that this line of code

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Item3, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="60" />
```

is updated to Mode = TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged. I would change to

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Item3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="60" />
```